# Как добавить matplotlib в контекстном меню promoted to Qt Designer?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt, qt-designer, matplotlib

Пытаюсь добавить на форму *Qt Designer* график из ****`matplotlib`****. 
Для этого использую функцию из контекстного меню `promoted to`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`Header file` я добавил сам модуль ***matplotlib*** имя выбрал в итоге при запуске получаю ошибку:

> AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'PlotWidget'

---

***matplotlib*** установлен.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вариант:

**q1505368_main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *

from q1505368_design import Ui_MainWindow

from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg


class MplCanvas(FigureCanvasQTAgg):                                 # !!! +++
    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=4, dpi = 100):
        fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)
        super(MplCanvas, self).__init__(fig)
        

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        sc = MplCanvas(self, width=5, height=4, dpi=100)            # !!! +++
        sc.axes.plot(
            [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], 
            [10, 1, 20, 3, 40]
        )
        
        lay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.mplWidget)
        lay.addWidget(sc)                                           # !!! +++

        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

**q1505368_design.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(741, 542)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        font.setItalic(True)
        MainWindow.setFont(font)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")

# !!!        
        self.mplWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)          # !!!
        self.mplWidget.setObjectName("mplWidget")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.mplWidget)        
        
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Как добавить matplotlib"))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]